# Application pool restart automaticly if file change in repositery

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, iis-7, application-pool

Why does the application restart automatically when we create a new folder under a web site in IIS 7.0 or Cassini?

Is it a config we can change ? What is the impact ?

I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330390/restart-asp-net-application-when-folder-contents-change) and the post not answer to my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solutions.

There is [the link](http://www.dominicpettifer.co.uk/Blog/36/stop-iis-appdomain-restarts-when-a-folder-is-deleted)

Put this code in the application start of the global.asax

```
PropertyInfo p = typeof(HttpRuntime).GetProperty("FileChangesMonitor", 
                BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static); 

            object o = p.GetValue(null, null); 

            FieldInfo f = o.GetType().GetField("_dirMonSubdirs", 
                BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.IgnoreCase); 

            object monitor = f.GetValue(o); 

            MethodInfo m = monitor.GetType().GetMethod("StopMonitoring", 
                BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic); 

            m.Invoke(monitor, new object[] { });
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue so I decided NOT to write files/folder on the root of my web app.
I noticed that on my dev computer but not on some servers (W2K3). Also try running the [AspNetCompiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164291.aspx) msbuild task to your site with updatable in false.